# Best UX practice when grouping items from one list to another

Tags: selection, multi-selection

I have been given some rough wireframes for a screen where the user needs to search from items on the right and assign them to a group on the left. Once items from the right have been assigned to a group they still exist in the right hand column but the Quantity assigned value increases.

[image]

This screen seems very confusing but I'm not sure what the best UI/UX design is when assigning items from a list to a group.

**What is the best UI/UX design when assigning a list of items to a group?**

I know drag and drop may potentially solve this but I feel in this case it may be over-engineering as this is supposed to be a quick simple screen.

Comment: How does the initial grouping mechanism work? What is the relationship between the top and bottom tables?

Comment: You select items on the right and click the "assign" button in the middle, this assigns them to the left hand column (group).. The relationship between the top table and the child tables is a parent/child relationship. In this example it is an Item (t-shirt for example) and the 3 sizes, small medium large

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists, but only one list is used to populate the other list, and so there is only a one-way flow of information, but you are asking the user to make a selection using the other list as well in the Assign user flow (this is my assumption since I don't know how the Unassign flow works). I think this is why the flow feels a little bit confusing.

You could design the screen so that all of the interactions happen one the one side of the screen in the one list (for example, by allow them to select the group(s) after you click on the Assign button), or you can create a flow for assign that starts from one side, and a flow for unassign that starts from the other side.

These are some suggestions but there is no best practice that is better than understanding the exact requirements and context for these user workflows and interface interactions.